# Checkbox com id no name

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox, toggle

Gostaria de estar com um botão checkbox no site para ativar e desativar alguma ação, estou usando ajax para fazer de imediato a mudança assim, a ação não precisaria de um f5 para funcionar. O problema é que estou passando o ID da div criada pelo php pelo name do do check e não parece estar funcinando pois o php não muda o valor do check para 1 no banco. Gostaria de mudar o valor dele de 1 - 0

```
<?
php
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");

    $ativado = $_POST['ativado'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

        $sql="UPDATE produto SET ID=$nome WHERE ativado='$ativado'";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

       echo $ativado;

     ?>
   <div class='col-3'>
              <label class='switch mt-3'>
                 <input class='input-check'type='checkbox' name='check".$row_produto['ID']."' value='0'>
                 <span class='check round'></span>
                </label>
                <button type='button'  class='close deletar mt-2'  id='".$row_produto['ID']." aria-label='Close'>
 <i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i>
</button>
    </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        var ativado = $(this).attr('value');
        var nome = $(this).attr('name');
        if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
            $('input[name=' + nome + ']').val('0');
            alert("Checkbox is checked. " + nome + "valor= " + ativado);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../php/ativo_produto.php',
                data: {
                    ativado: ativado,
                    nome: name,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            })

        } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
            $('input[name=' + nome + ']').val('1');
            alert("Checkbox is checked. " + nome + "valor= " + ativado);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../php/ativo_produto.php',
                data: {
                    ativado: ativado,
                    nome: name,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Quando tá checado o valor do checkbox fica `0`, e quando não tá o valor fica `1`? Não seria o contrário?

Comment: isso, eu mudei sem querer. Mas de qualquer jeito ele nem chega a ser chamado ou mudado no banco

Comment: O que quer dizer com nem é chamado? Não dá o alert? Tem vários problemas

Comment: ele não é alterado, pois o valor que está lá é 0 e queria trocar para 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Um erro é que você está passando `name` na variável `nome` no `data`
>   do AJAX. O correto seria `nome: nome`, e não `nome: name`.

Mas como você quer passar um `id`, que seria um número, coloque um atributo `data-id` no checkbox com o `id` vindo do PHP e envie esse valor no AJAX.

> Faltou também fechar o atributo `id` do `button` com aspas simples:
>
> ```
> id='".$row_produto['ID']."'
>                           ↑
> ```

Coloque no checkbox:

```
<input class='input-check'type='checkbox' data-id='".$row_produto['ID']."' name='check".$row_produto['ID']."' data-id="1" value='0'>
                                             ↑↑↑
```

Você pode fazer de uma forma mais simples. Não precisa usar um `if` para repetir o mesmo código AJAX. Com um só código AJAX você consegue enviar os valores corretamente (`0` ou `1`) na variável `ativado` e o respectivo `id`. O uso do `this` é útil nestes casos porque ele referencia o objeto que disparou o evento.

Veja como fica bem simples o código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
      var nome = this.name; // pega o name o checkbox clicado
      this.value = this.checked ? '1' : '0'; // muda o value para '1' se tiver checado, e '0' deschecado
      var ativado = this.value; // pega o valor do checkbox
      var id = $(this).data("id"); // pega o id no data-id

      alert("Checkbox is checked. " + nome + "valor= " + ativado);
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '../php/ativo_produto.php',
         data: {
            ativado: ativado,
            id: id,
         },
         success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
         }
      });
   });
});
```

E no PHP altere o POST `$name` para:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

E no SQL:

```
$sql="UPDATE produto SET ID='$id' WHERE ativado='$ativado'";
```

Comment: Eu testei mas mesmo assim não parece resolver, ele realmente troca no html, dá pra ver com o inspecionar mas não chega a mandar pro banco ... o valor não vai de jeito algum para o banco. ah sim, quando eu peço um echo no php pra ver qual valor ele está mandando, ele manda o do value mais nunca aparece o de id no echo, fica vazio

Comment: Eu testei aqui e funcionou certinho. Veja se fez tudo correto como explica a resposta.

Comment: pode ser por eu estar colocando o id do banco ? pq eu n estou criando ela como html, ela está sendo criada dinamicamente como um php e chamada pro html

Comment: Não seria: `"UPDATE produto SET ativado='$ativado' WHERE ID='$id'"`?

Comment: SIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIM, foi isso mesmo!!! Eu jurava que este código estava certo. Muito obrigado de coração, faz muito tempo que estou parado nisso e n sabia o por que, já estava desanimando pq não é uma coisa tão complexa assim e eu já estava martelando aqui

Answer (score 1):

Você está setando `ativado`com o attributo value, que é fixo como sendo "0". Ele deve receber o valor de 0 ou 1 dependendo do checked. Os blocos if e else também não precisam conter todo o código, só precisa colocar ali se vai mandar 0 ou 1; ou ainda usar o operador ternary para ficar mais sucinto.

```
<div>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkProd1' data-id='Prod1'>
  <label for="checkProd1">prod 1</label><br />
  <input type='checkbox' name='checkProd2' data-id='Prod2'>
  <label for="checkProd2">prod 2</label><br />
  <input type='checkbox' name='checkProd3' data-id='Prod3'>
  <label for="checkProd2">prod 3</label><br />
 </div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        var ativado = $(this).prop('checked') ? 1 : 0;
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        alert("Checkbox " + id + " ativado? " + ativado);
      /* $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../php/ativo_produto.php',
                data: {
                    ativado: ativado,
                    id: id,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
       })*/
    });
});
```

Veja esse exemplo funcionado aqui: https://playcode.io/324057?tabs=console&script.js&output